# Commits not appearing in GitHub commit history or code (it is successfully committed locally on my desktop)

Tags: github, git-commit

[successfully committed locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MBNc.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVNqf.png)

[github profile img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BOCi.png)

I am encountering an issue where certain commits made to my GitHub repository are not visible in the commit history or reflected in the code. I have verified the branch, email configuration, and remote URL settings to ensure everything is correct. However, despite committing locally without any error messages, the commits do not show up on GitHub. Other commits are visible, and I have confirmed that I am viewing the correct branch and timeframe. Is there a potential reason for this discrepancy? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Additional Details:

Repository: The affected repository is located at (https://github.com/tanvirkamble/RESTful-api).
Branch: I have confirmed that I am viewing the correct branch on the GitHub repository page.
Commit Details: The missing commits include relevant information such as the commit message, date, and time.
Email Configuration: The email address associated with my Git configuration matches the one linked to my GitHub account.
I have already reviewed potential solutions like checking the correct branch, verifying the email configuration, and ensuring the remote URL is accurate. However, the commits are still not visible. I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure the commits are properly reflected in the GitHub commit history and code.

Thank you for your assistance and insights.

Comment: Did you try to push your changes? You're missing a commit on the remote that you didn't fetch, which you need to either merge or rebase, and you've got four commits you made locally but did not push yet.

Comment: yea push was the issue, thannks.